# Google app engine: 502 Bad Gateway only on POST requests

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

So I deployed a nodeJS script on GAE and whenever I hit a POST endpoint I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. The endpoint is a simple service that grabs a screenshot of a page using phantomJS and returns a JSON that contains the base64 representation of the image in it.

Doing a GET to this endpoint works fine and returns a healthy 200 response, however as soon as I try a POST request I get: **502 Bad Gateway**

Here is my **app.yaml**:

```
service: pdf-service

# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
# [END runtime]

threadsafe: yes

# Temporary setting to keep gcloud from uploading node_modules
skip_files:
 - ^node_modules$

handlers:
- url: (.*)/
  script: app.js
  secure: always
```

My **app.js** script:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var phantom = require('./phantom');

app.use(cors());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

var tmpURL = 'https://www.google.com';
// [START hello_world]
// Say hello!
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('requrl', req.body);
    phantom.takeScreenShot(tmpURL, res);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({'greetings': 'Hello World'});
});
// [END hello_world]

if (module === require.main) {
    // [START server]
    // Start the server
    var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function() {
        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;

        console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
    });
    // [END server]
}

module.exports = app;
```

Notes:
**The code works on my local environment.**

Comment: Does the code works on your local dev environment?

Comment: @VikramTiwari yes it works perfectly on my local environment.

Comment: @HarrisRobinKalash Were you able to solve it? I'm facing the same problem..

Comment: @DanielGolub unfortunately no, I have up on having it on GAE and just put it on heroku where it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472049/502-bad-gateway-with-nginx-google-app-engine-node-js):

Reading the logs helped me see what was causing the issue on my endpoint. i.e.

"gcloud app logs read"