# 502 Bad Gateway and "Please try again in 30 seconds" messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

First of all I know that http 502 on gcloud means any possible error. 
Also, **in logs there are no errors** only standard spring boot info and debug messages.

The project I have troubles is a swagger generated spring boot java project (more than 160 java files).

Locally on intellij works well and fast.

After executing *mvn clean spring-boot:run* on gclod shell the project starts and I see the default generated page on the browser.

After executing `mvn  appengine:deploy` on gclod shell I always see this message on the browser:
*Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds*
or This error: *502 Bad Gateway nginx*. Always.

This are the last messages from gcloud console (after mvn  appengine:deploy):

```
..done.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Setting traffic split for service [default]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: ...................................done.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Deployed service [default] to [https://polishapi-psd2.appspot.com]
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: You can stream logs from the command line by running:
[INFO] GCLOUD:   $ gcloud app logs tail -s default
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: To view your application in the web browser run:
[INFO] GCLOUD:   $ gcloud app browse
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-18T14:11:30+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\workspace\PolishAPI-psd2>gcloud app logs tail
```

**In logs there are no errors**.
A basic, super simple, spring boot "hello world" project works but not that swagger generated big one.

How to deal with this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm from GCP Support. I saw that you have now a working Swagger app; is the issue solved, then?

Comment: YES YES YES!  :)  without changing source code I discovered that this two lines in app.yaml file are enought: runtime: `
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4


`

Comment: I'm glad you solved your issue! :D

Comment: I still don't understand why only java11 runtime and standard environment works, but java and flex environment doesn't. In google docs there are no explanation. So,**the issue is not solved** , I used only a **workaround**.

Comment: 1/3-After checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472049/502-bad-gateway-with-nginx-google-app-engine-node-js), I recommend you to thoroughly go through the logs of your app ([Viewing Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview), [Debugging an Instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance)), in order to diagnose the reason for this error.

Comment: 2/3-You may also provide them in this post, after removing any personal security information(if needed) so I (and possibly other community members) can investigate further.

Comment: 3/3-Additionally, these links ([Choosing Env](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), [Key differences](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/flexible-for-standard-users#similarities_and_key_differences), [Migrating](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating)) point out the differences between flexible and standard environment, so I figured out they might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with this problem for more than 4 weeks I discovered that the app.yaml file should only contain this two lines:

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
```

yes! only this two lines are enought to run on gcloud that swagger generated project.
There are so many different samples on stackoverflow, github, etc. including **unalike** sample app.yaml files made by google **for the same task** and the answer is so simple.

Best regards! :)

Answer (score 1):

Exact same issue , i am having for this sample https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/helloworld-springboot

Followed the two lines   it worked. 
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4

Answer (score 0):

By analogy with the answers above, the following helped:

```
runtime: java
env: flex    
instance_class: B4
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  memory_gb: 4
```

It can also be used if necessary `automatic_scaling` and `instance_class` F4.